# Are solvent effects the reason for the methoxide ion to be a stronger nucleophile than the thiomethoxide ion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilicity

Between $\ce{CH3O-}$ and $\ce{NC-}$, $\ce{NC-}$ is a better nucleophile than $\ce{CH3O-}$ in a polar protic solvent, while $\ce{CH3O-}$ is a better one in a polar aprotic solvent, because in a polar aprotic solvent $\ce{CH3O-}$ is free to move and $\ce{O-}$ has more electron density.

Does the same reason apply for $\ce{CH3O-}$ and $\ce{CH3S-}$, is $\ce{CH3O-}$ a stronger nucleophile than the latter one in polar aprotic solvent?

Comment: I think you're overestimating influence of solvents.